# choosing json structure based on sibling property

Tags: jsonpath

I have a nested json structure in which there are different types of structures. Some structures contain `property` and `propertytype`. I want to choose all structures in which `propertyType==cloudProperty`. I don't know the format of the json structure, so recursive descent is necessary.

I tried `jsonpath.query(body, '$..*[?(propertyType=="cloudProperty")]`, which to my knowledge should do a recursive descent on root and find all structures in which the `propertyType` parameter, if it exists, == "cloudProperty". This returns an empty array.

What I ideally want is to get all `property`s where `propertyType==cloudProperty`, but propertyType is a sibling of property, not a child node.

From what I see in the debugger, `jsonpath` does an iterative depth-first search, adding each node to the array as it is added to the call stack. But is the jsonpath syntax able to support getting all structures where a sibling type fulfills a condition?

Example of

```
0: Object... {
   property: "foo",
   propertyType: "bar",
   value: {
      property: "foo2",
      propertyType: "cloudProperty"
   }
},
1: Object... {
    property: "foo3",
    propertyType: "bsr",
}
```

The problem is these objects may not even exist. `property` might be 1 to n levels down.

Comment: Can you put an example of the JSON up

Comment: It's really nested and can change. I can put up an example of what the node which contains both property and structure looks like